# ShellExtension AddPages isn't called

Tags: c++, com, contextmenu, shell-extensions, propertysheet

I am trying to implement a PropertySheetHandler shell extension, without much luck.

For some reason, the ContextMenu handlers are successfully called (`Initialize()` and `QueryContextMenu()`) but `AddPages()` is not called.

I have implemented the `IShellPropSheetExt` interface (`AddPages()` and `ReplacePages()`) and have the following declared:

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CShellExtension)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IShellExtInit)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IContextMenu)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IShellPropSheetExt)
END_COM_MAP()
```

Also, in the Registry I added the following entry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\MyPropSheet
```

And of course also added to the CLSID:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CC669AD3-9F45-4C29-ADF7-F2F58E2DB2E9}\InprocServer32
```

With the DLL path and ThreadingModel Apartment (also tried Both).

What am I missing?

I also ran Process Monitor, and I can see my DLL is found, yet no call to Initialize or AddPages is made upon file properties.

Comment: I have an app that implements a combo ContextMenu+PropertySheet DLL, and it works fine for both types of handlers. In the Registry, did you set the `(Default)` value of your `MyPropSheet` key to be your CLSID? Have you tried creating your key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\*\...` and/or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\...` instead of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` directly?

Comment: See the MSDN documentation: [How to Register and Implement a Property Sheet Handler for a File Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127448.aspx), [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx) and [Merged View of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724498.aspx)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I followed the msdn instructions and went through your registry suggestions, All were OK, except for HKCU which I added the *\... registries yet it is still not working